# Setting up rsyslog filter

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I am writing something and I wanted to take advantage of Linux API for logging, I wanted to put the logs of my app to different files, so I added those lines to rsyslog.conf

```
if $programname == 'RearWindowDaemon' then /var/log/RearWindowDaemon.log 
if $programname == 'RearWindow' then /var/log/RearWindow.log
```

but something is not working, even with this simple code:

```
int main()
{
openlog("RearWindow",0,LOG_LOCAL0);
syslog(LOG_ERR,"some err");
syslog(LOG_ERR,"other err");
return;
}
```

I get the logs to `/var/log/syslog` and not to `/var/log/RearWindow`.

Should I do anything more? I am using XUbuntu 11.10 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's late a bit. But what I can understand, you should compile your code such that it produces the binary with name 'RearWindow'. $programname checks if logs are coming from a process with the specified name not that the log contains the string 'RearWindow'.  Hopefully this helps.